# Applying regression in subsample - adding fitted values to dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, lm

I have a problem adding my fitted `lm()` values to the original dataset.
The problem started once I ran the `lm()` on a subsample of the original dataset. For example:

```
 a <- lm(y ~ x, subset = a=='yes', data= df)
 df$fit <- fitted(a)
```

I get an error

> Error in '$<-.data.frame'(' ... replacement has 2000 rows, data has 6000 rows.

I understand that this is due to the fact that the vector of the fitted values is much shorter than the length of the dataset, however, I need to run the analysis on a subsample and keep `NA`s for the cases not selected for the analysis.

Is there a way to run `lm()` on a subsample of the original dataset and add the fitted values without having to subset the dataset or get the above error?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `df$fit[which(df$a=="yes")] = fitted(a)`. The LHS and RHS need to have the same number of rows (and of course you want the rows on the LHS to be the correct rows!).

Comment: Thank you eipi10 for your response, unfortunately, I get the same error

Comment: Try df$fit=NA first, then run the code in my first comment.